# What are the credentials for Neo4j browser

Tags: authentication, neo4j

I have just installed neo4j [desktop](https://neo4j.com/download/) and also the server from [here](https://neo4j.com/download-center/#releases).

Also installed [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Next I had extracted the neo4j community and then using the **admin** command prompt inside the bin directory at that location I had installed the service using the command

```
neo4j.bat install-service.
```

Once the services are successfully installed, I am now able to browse to http://localhost:7474/browser/

But now what? What should be the credentials to logon.

I see the following messages

**Database access not available. Please use :server connect  to establish connection. There's a graph waiting for you.**

**Connect to Neo4j
Database access requires an authenticated connection.**

[image: Neo4j browser authentication problem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default credentials are

```
Username: neo4j 
Password: neo4j
```

Comment: just saved a day :)

Comment: I just downloaded `neo4j-desktop-canary-1.5.8-dev.0-x86_64.AppImage` (recomandet for Ubuntu?) and started the app image, was then asked for registration and email (apparently not without it), then some things were downloaded and then neo4j started, I clicked on MovieDatabase and was asked to login with user `neo4j`. Thought the default password is both times `neo4j`?
I always get the error:  `Database access not available. Please use  :server connect to establish connection. There's a graph waiting for you.`